# Laravel 5.5 the payload is invalid response in postman when trying to decrypt string

Tags: laravel

Im trying to decrypt string that will be send by the other user using other platform. we are using the same encryption type (AES-256-CBC). when i pass the encrypted string in my body and call the api i get **The payload is invalid** message. please someone explain me the issue and also help me find out what the **key** is in this encryption method and where is the key in my project..
[Currently im using the app key for key], when i encrypt a string in my project and pass it to the body, i get the required output but not when i use the encrypted value from other user. 
[image: using postman to send the encrypted value]

[image: the controller called by the api]

Comment: the problem seems to be with the string that you are sending with postman, its invalid. What if you store the string in code and pass it to decryptor:  $payload =base64_decode( 'your encoded string here');   dd(Crypt::decryptString($payload));

Comment: the string will come from other system users in encrypted form, soo i think i have to pass it in the postman. i tired the way you said but didnt work!!